# Get a result from actvity inside adapter and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

My question is simple (or not). Imagine the scenario:
I have an Activity, call a fragment and inside this fragment I have an BaseAdapter. In a button which is in the item of adapter, I need to call another Activity and this Activity needs to return a result for me to continue the proccess started in the adapter button.

Is there any chance to do that?
I imagine that with onActivityResult I get something, but the problem is how to return to item in adapter?

Well, I don't know if I was cleary enough, but that's it.

Comment: What do you want to do in the item adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can communicate between the first activity and the fragment with the help of an interface.
Call a method of that fragment that sets up the adapter when activity 2 sends the result in onActivityResult method.

Comment: I need to call a method that only exists in the adapter when I finish the proccess, so I can't do it in onActivityResult.